¿Cómo puedo implementar jwt si estoy usando next auth en mi proyecto Next js junto con el proveedor de Google para conectarme a una API en Flask?
Estoy creando una aplicación web que necesita consumir una API de flask. La autenticación se realiza inicialmente mediante next auth, pero me gustaría que la aplicación web consuma un servicio de una ruta de mi api flask. Pero quiero que esta ruta sea protegida y unicamente la puedan consumir usuarios con sesión iniciada en la app web.
Pensaba en implementar jwt pera ya que en inicio la sesión se inicia usando la cuenta google con next auth, estoy perdido con cual es el camino correcto a seguir.
